# Optimizing IIS 6.0 performance on Windows Server 2003 Operating System

Tags: asp.net, iis, optimization, web

.
Hi,
     We have built an ASP.NET application (with C#.net language) and hosted on IIS 6.0 on Windows Server 2003 Operating System.

Now we need to optimize the IIS performance so that the pages get served fast.

Would you please let me know if you have any idea on this?

If would be great if you could provide the relevant doc or web reference (If needed).

Many Thanks,
Regards,
Venkat.
 .

Answer (score 0):

its not really a question of tuning the iis, as much as your code.

**iis**

- tune your caching and compression settings
- only have one default document
- don't use extensionless handlers

these settings are virtually pointless though if the code you have written is not optimized

**asp.net**

- never run in debug mode
- be carefull with exceptions since they are expensive
- use page and usercontrol caching correctly
- set caching, etag and expires headers correctly on your http-response
- compress your javascript and stylesheets (there is different 3rd party components for this)
- reduce the number of http requests

  - use sprites for small image icons etc.

**links**

- http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/25d2170b-09c0-45fd-8da4-898cf9a7d568.mspx?mfr=true
- http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/71490aae-f444-443c-8b2a-520c2961408e.mspx?mfr=true
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag
- http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html